# findViewWithTag returns null

Tags: android, android-viewpager

This is the problem that I am working on.

I'm trying to set up `ViewPagers` to load 3 `XML` file.
Let's call it `ViewPagerAdapter.java`

On the object Instantiate, I tried to change all the textfield fonts using `findViewWithTag()`.
But when the `EditText` is defined with `findViewWithTag()`, it returns `null` (Using `system.out.println`) which caused the `setTypeFace` error.

Did I do wrong with the code?

```
Object Instantiate Code (ViewPagerAdapter.java)

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;

        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.activity_login;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.activity_register;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.activity_vote;
            break;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        EditText txtFields = (EditText) view.findViewWithTag("abeezee");
            txtFields.setTypeFace(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); //This one cause the error (Line 39)
        System.out.println(txtFields);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
```

One of the XML (activity_register.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layRegister"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterTitle"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/register_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNameReg"
        style="@style/textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spVoteMlm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" 
        android:tag="abeezee"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmailReg"
        style="@style/textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
        android:tag="abeezee"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordReg"
        style="@style/textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etEmailReg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmailReg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:tag="abeezee"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spVoteMlm"
        style="@style/textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegisterTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:entries="@array/mlm_list" 
        android:tag="abeezee"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        style="@style/buttonBlue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTerms"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/register_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTerms"
        style="@style/smallLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPasswordReg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"   
        android:onClick="showTermsPolicy"
        android:text="@string/terms_policy" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat error :

```
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at com.sociyo.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:39)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15392)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:622)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:404)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15392)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15392)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:578)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15392)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2154)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15392)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1865)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1286)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1011)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4244)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-24 13:17:49.178: E/AndroidRuntime(16278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You must identifies the tag with EditText as well. DVM does not find any element with above tag hence return null.

Comment: Like android:tag="abeezee"

Comment: Use the ID of the "EditText", so that line 38 would look like: `EditText txtFields = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNameReg);`

Comment: I think I've already done that. You could check on the posted XML

Comment: why are you using tag u already used the id..? to solve the problem just replace the findViewWithTag with findViewById as id is your layout

Comment: @shoerat The reason I didn't use findViewById because I don't want to define and then change the typeface one by one. By giving each textfields a tag, I should get a fewer line in changing the typeface.

Comment: @ArpitGarg So you are saying that the Id and Tag cannot be use at the same time?

Comment: @YansenTan, there clearly is a problem with your approach. You can't have same tag for several views (even the types are different!) and expect `findViewWithTag()` to return their instances correctly.

Comment: Even I use the findViewById(), I still getting the null error. Are you guys sure this is the problem with findView?

Comment: @YansenTan No I mean you can use both ways.But the problem is that as already explained by "shoe rat" that you are using same tag with different view types. The tag must be unique

Comment: Have you set tag for all three EditTexts??

Comment: I see. It seems that I mistakenly use this tagging. I thought the function of this tag is the same with the xcode one. Do you guys know how to select all element at once using tagging in android? (Button, textfields, and other element)

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Yes, I set the same tag to all EditText, as you can see the XML file, I put the abeezee tag there. I thought by using tag, I don't have to define each textfield(or maybe other like button) to set the Typeface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `getViewsByTag` function to iterate from a parent element and get all the "tagged" child elements it contains.  Then you can iterate over those view and use a `switch` statement and `instanceof` to handle `Button`, `EditText` or `TextView` elements differently if you want.

```
public static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
        } 

        final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
        if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
            views.add(child);
        }

    }
    return views;
}
```